# 1/10th of My Automator Actions Are Suddenly In Spanish

Tags: automator, language

Anyone hazard a guess as to why?

I have not changed my System language settings to Spanish, have not ventured with any Mac/iDevices to a country where the primary language is Spanish and nothing else on my machine(s) seems to have been translated...

The actions in question all appear in the System/Library/Automator folder with English filenames. They were all added on March 28th, presumably installed as part of the last Mac OS update, and were included as part of a group of 64 actions, the majority of which are in English. Within Automator, the action names and descriptions are in Spanish.

Why? And can I force the OS to translate them to English or install English versions of these actions?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWE3n.png]

Comment: Already tried to reinstall the [combo updater 10.12.4](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1910)?

Comment: No. I have not tried reinstalling anything. You think that might correct it?

Comment: I would try it, yes! At least it doesn't harm anything!